# How to install Dart to be used in the terminal? (command line)

Tags: bash, command-line, path, dart, installation

How do you install Dart so the language can be used within the terminal? (For UNIX based systems, such as a Mac)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After installing Dart (currently located at https://www.dartlang.org/), you will need to do some additional work to use dart commands in the terminal (command line), as it needs to be added to the Bash profile `PATH`s (on a UNIX based system). To do this, run the following handy command to open the `.bash_profile` file in it’s default location and with the system’s default text editor `touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile`.

Next find the directory that Dart was downloaded to and put the path for `dart-sdk/bin` inside the `.bash_profile` as apart of the `PATH` variable. I.e. a line of code should be added to this file that looks something like this (if you’ve put the dart install in the applications folder on a Mac): `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Dart/dart-sdk/bin`.

To get Bash to start using this new profile immediately without restart, enter `source ~/.bash_profile` in the terminal (command line), then to double check the PATHs have updated, by enter in the command `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

1) Install Dart in your environment (if have not yet)

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk#install

2) Add PATH variable for dart/bin

Example for Ubuntu

```
# add path example
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source .bashrc
```

or it can be .bash_profile instead of .bashrc

3) And now just run your .dart file with the main() method in the terminal and see an output

```
$ dart path_to_your_file/your_file_with_main.dart
```